# Proof that given $\sigma \in S_n$ is $p$-cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

> Given in my book is that if $p$ is prime and $\sigma \in S_n$ such that $\sigma\neq(1)$ and $\sigma^p=(1)$ with $ \frac{1}{2}n<p\leq n$. Prove that $\sigma$ is a $p$-cycle.

I can prove that $\text{order}\ (\sigma)=p$ and that if we write $\sigma=\sigma_1\cdots\sigma_m$ that every $\sigma_i$ has length $1$ or $p$. So it is left to prove that there is only one $\sigma_i$ with length equal to $p$. How to prove this?

Comment: user26857: Indeed, thank you!

Comment: user26857, I already expected this, yet (silly enough) I do not see the last step.

Comment: *Hint* : $2p>n$

Comment: I already noticed this, but this still does not lead to full proof for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the cicles are disjoint, then if you have more than 1 $p$-cicle, they must contain at least $2p$ distinct numbers, but $2p>n$ gives the contradiction.

Comment: Thank you! It was quite silly to miss this step, but it is all clear now.